# how to use another JS file in content script's JS file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, es6-modules, content-script

I had defined a content script in the `manifest.json` as:

```json
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://*/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "cs.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

And in `cs.js` I would like to load another JS ([`mark.js`](https://markjs.io)) as module:

```js
// cs.js
import Mark from './lib/mark.es6.min.js'
window.onload = (event) => {
  console.log(Mark)
}
```

and when I am visiting any page, there is an error in the console

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

The directory structure looks like:

```
manifest.json
cs.js
lib/mark.es6.min.js
```

What is the best way in which I can load the [mark.js](https://markjs.io) to be able to use in my content script?

Comment: You can use multiple content scripts. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24227874/can-i-share-code-between-different-parts-of-chrome-extension

Comment: See also [How to import ES6 modules in content script for Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48104433)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [1j01](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2624876/), [woxxom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/) and [nicola-scionti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17672228/) for good suggestions ([Can I share code between different parts of Chrome Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24227874/can-i-share-code-between-different-parts-of-chrome-extension), [How to import ES6 modules in content script for Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48104433) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/70359345/725306 respectively).

I ended up using `content_scripts` only as:

```
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://*/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "lib/mark.es6.min.js",
                "cs.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

and then simply use that in my `cs.js`

```
// cs.js
window.onload = (event) => {
  console.log(Mark)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked for, but be aware that you can spawn different scripts from the background page:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
  file: "./content_scripts/script1.js",
});

chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
  file: "./content_scripts/script2.js",
});
```

And then, the functions you declare in `script1.js` can be used in `script2.js`

Comment: I assume "scripts from the background page" by this you are referring to https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/service_workers/. right? and the snippet to be placed in script file referred from `background.service_worker` in `manifest.json`.

Comment: Yes, i'm referring to that script